# Why does one need to use "%~dpf0" parameter to assign a non-printable character to variable?

Tags: batch-file

I saw the `%~dpf0` parameter (that returns the absolute part of the currently executed batch-script) used with the `copy /Z` command, like

```
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "ASCII_13=%%a"
```

to assign a special character to the variable `ASCII_13`, as in [this](https://superuser.com/a/492067/823373) answer. Now I get that the part

```
copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul
```

is used to produce that special character (carriage return), but how exactly does it work?

Is the current batch-file entered here only as source of `copy`, because it is certain that it is an existing file and we just need an actual file here to have `copy` execute successfully?

Comment: Just a note that you should be able to successfully use, `%~f0` or even `%~0`, there should never be a need to use `%~dpf0`.

Comment: Pretty much.  Don't over think it. We know the batch file exists so it is used with the copy command.

Comment: See [Why ~dpf ?](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8536)

Comment: @Compo False, this is only true when your batch file is in the current directory.